# processing.runalg('qgis:splitvectorlayer') --> wrong Output directory

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, splitting

I'm tryiing to split a vector layer using this code :

```
processing.runalg('qgis:splitvectorlayer', 'D:/Images_Sentinel_2/2A/shp_taitt/contour.shp', 'nom', 'D:/Images_Sentinel_2/2A/shp_taitt_split')
```

the problem is that the output files are saved in 'D:/Images_Sentinel_2/2A/shp_taitt' not in 'D:/Images_Sentinel_2/2A/shp_taitt_split'

I tried to run it manually in two ways, one of them is working and the other one is not

the first one is not saved in the processing history, but it save output files in the output directory: 
[image]

the second one is saved in the processing history but it doesn't save output files in the output directory given as parameter
[image]

Comment: Try running it manually then check the Processing history to see the code used.

Comment: I tried it but the problem is that even doing it manually it give the same thing : the files are not saved in the output directory. I tried to run it in two ways I will apdate the question and put screenshots

Comment: I think it is VectorSplit.py in osgeo4w\apps\qgis-ltr\python\plugins\processing\algs\qgis. Inside the code there is an feedpack.pushInfo, it should write the created filename to the journal tab. Can you check the output there?

Comment: Oh, what version of QGIS do you use, I was assuming it's 3.x.

Comment: actually it's 2.14.12

that s what I get when running the splitvectorlayer :

 `{'OUTPUT': 'D:\\Images_Sentinel_2\\2A\\shp_taittinger_split'} ` 

but the files are not saved in this directory

Comment: @Namoat - It could be an issue with that specific version. Could you try a more up-to-date version of QGIS?